# QField packages my project but I cant see some files on my tablet

Tags: csv, qfield

I am packaging a QField project and the packaging shows no errors. When I copy it to my tablet and open the file, it says two of my files are unable to load. One of the files is a CSV and the other is a shapefile I have converted from a CSV.